# How would I show the particles.js library in a flask application?

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

Currently I've first created a regular website with everything functioning in html and CSS the way I want. Now upon converting it to a Web App I'm confused on implementing the particles.json file that's needed in configuring the particles on the web page. I placed the file in it's static folder for flask. But for the script and having flask relay it over is where I need help in as I'm new to flask.

Currently the script is at default in index.html file and its subsequent related pages as:

```
<script
src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js">
</script>

<script>
    particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.json',
    function(){
    console.log('particles.json has loaded');

});

</script>
```

app.py file where I assume in relaying the script will go:

```
flask imports and stuff here 

    @route('/')
    def index():
        return render_template("index.html")

    if __name__ == '__main__':
         app.run(debug=True)
```

I was already able to connect everything design and back-end wise to the site however, the particles do not show and I'm assuming it's because I haven't done what I am asking how to do now in flask.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a static folder and declare it:

```
app = Flask(__name__,
            static_url_path='', 
            static_folder='web/static',
            template_folder='web/templates')
```

Then create the path for the static folder, in this case web/static.

If you put your json file in web/static then Flask will be able to serve it.

Comment: I did the code above but changed the web to be my folder name, and the .json file is located in the static folder already though this didn't work gave internal server error did I miss something

Comment: Which internal server error did it give you? the path should be relative to your script, so if you do python app.py in a folder called my_project, where you want to serve files from a folder called static, you'd give it the path 'static/' (dont include the name of your project folder) -> Alternatively you can pass an absolute path. Post the error if you cant figure it out and ill try my best to help you.

Comment: It was my own fault, I had a few additional slashes in the ending of some routes which blocked the js file from showing on all pages. And since I was using VS Code apparently my path had to be in full and not a shortcut. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your template file:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/particles.js@2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
<script>
    particlesJS.load("particles-js", "{{ url_for('static', filename='particles.json') }}",
    function(){
    console.log("particles.json has loaded");
});
</script>
```

Make sure you have 'url_for' imported in your app:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
```

Then just put your particles.json in a folder called 'static' in your project directory.